# Why isn't StaticResource for image found at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, embedded-resource

I've added an image to my Resources.resx file. I reference it like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding MyImage}"/>
```

In the designer, I do see a squiggly blue line under the above. It says

> The resource "MyImage" could not be resolved.

At runtime, it throws this error:

> Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an
>   exception.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `MyImage` in your binding context? What does your model look like? Did you mean to use `StaticResource` or `DynamicResource` instead of Binding?

Comment: No - it isn't in the binding context. I'm pretty sure this is `StaticResource`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `resx` files with WPF, you'd have to add some code to make the interop work. Images in `resx` files are primarily used for WinForms code.

Set the *Build Action* to *Resource* in the file properties:

[image: build action]

Then just reference the file directly: `<Image Source="../../Some/Relative/Path.png"/>`

Neither `{Binding}` nor `{StaticResource}` is needed there.

Comment: If the Build Action is Resource, there is no "relative path" that starts with "../". Actually, it is a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) without the `pack://application:,,,/` prefix, which is automatically added by the XAML parser.

Comment: @Clemens you can also use a path relative to the xaml file if the resource is in the same assembly. I used `../` to indicate a parent directory.